# Cannot Render Image from API

Tags: android, reactjs, api, react-native

I have created my own website and api which is (https://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com) i already upload the image and can view as (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/notifications/August2019/c1nsEktOjtSloxEtnL4d.jpg). And my api for this id is (http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications/33). But when i try to fetch the api i can display all my text but not my image and hyperlink to download file. How to solve this issue

I try to use this but still no luck
{{ uri: member.image }}

```
    <Image
        value={member ? member.image : ''} 
        source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + member}}
        style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
      />
```

I expected to get my my image and my file using hyperink to download through google browser

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  InputWithLabel
} from './UI';
import { FloatingAction } from 'react-native-floating-action';

type Props = {};
export default class ShowScreen extends Component<Props> {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle')
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      id: this.props.navigation.getParam('id'),
      member: [],
    };

    this._load = this._load.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._load();
  }

  _load() {
    let url = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications/' + this.state.id;

    fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
    .then((member) => {
      this.setState({member});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    let member = this.state.member;
   // let af = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/';
    console.log(member);
    console.log(member.image);
    //let image = JSON.parse(member.image)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Title'}
            value={member ? member.title : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Department'}
            value={member ? member.department : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={styles.output}
            label={'Publish'}
            value={member ? member.updated_at : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
          />
          <InputWithLabel style={[styles.output, {height: 800, textAlignVertical: 'top'}]}
            label={'Description'}
            value={member ? member.description : ''}
            orientation={'vertical'}
            editable={false}
            multiline={true}
          />
          <Image
            value={member ? member.image : ''} 
            source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + this.state.member.image[0]}}
            style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
          />  
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  output: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#000099',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Try this - source={{uri: `http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/${member}`}}

Comment: @ravibagul91 should i quote it and should i remove the value?

Comment: It's a string literal like `.

Comment: @ravibagul91 does not work

Comment: What is member? Do console.log(member) and post output here.

Comment: member is my json that i retreive from api

Comment: so `member.image` complete image path?

Comment: If `member.image` is complete path then do this - source={{uri: member.image }}

Comment: If it's just a image name then do this - source={{uri: `http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/${member.image}`}}

Comment: Also check this - https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-are-template-literals-5d08a50ef2e3

Comment: gimme a min i try to console.log

Comment: here is my console.log(member)
https://imgur.com/a/aCT03cX
when i click member.image nothing show up

Comment: You are getting array of images,  you can do this - source={{uri: `http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/${member.image[0]}`}}

Comment: @ravibagul91 no luck with that too

Comment: I think you are confused with template literal, do this - `source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + member.image[0]}}`

Comment: @ravibagul91 sorry i did use that, but the error show now is cannot read property '0' of undefiened

Comment: i already updated my code see if anything i need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting array of `image` in `member` object. Which is also `stringified` version, you need to parse it to use further.

You can try this.

```
render() {
    let member = this.state.member;
    let af = 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/';

    let image = member && JSON.parse(member.image) //parse your array first

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          ...     
          <Image 
            source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + image[0]}}
            style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
          />  
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

---

**Update**

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wbqdxu)

Tested with below JSON directly, because we are getting `CORS` error while accessing your `URL`.

```
{"id":33,"title":"UTAR (Sungai Long Campus) Career Day","description":"<p style=\"margin: 0px 0px 6px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #1c1e21;\">DARP s organizing UTAR (Sungai Long Campus) Career Day and the details are as follows:-<\/p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\r\n<p style=\"margin: 6px 0px 0px; display: inline; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #1c1e21;\">Date: 1 August 2019 (Thursday)<br \/>Time: 10.00am - 4.00pm<br \/>Venue: Multipurpose Hall (KB Block), Sungai Long Campus<\/p>","image":"[\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/c1nsEktOjtSloxEtnL4d.jpg\",\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/WKka4FvUxFyNQpGQHSo8.jpg\",\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/KWKZ4XnlkjlK7vHEdHln.jpg\",\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/eNDFFu4hFHFMBEsR94DV.jpg\",\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/IWH0eg3IpG59qapIoHj3.jpg\"]","attachment":"[{\"download_link\":\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/SXMtnNb31ndgDnCWNC57.txt\",\"original_name\":\"dsadasdsa.txt\"},{\"download_link\":\"notifications\\\/August2019\\\/CDEZG6tJhrbVuxlfMiBb.txt\",\"original_name\":\"fyprefereance.txt\"}]","department":"D3E","link":null,"created_at":"2019-08-03 03:52:11","updated_at":"2019-08-03 03:52:11","deleted_at":null}
```

You can check the `console.log`, how the `member.parse` gives correct array of image.

---

**Update 2**

You can loop over `image` to get all the images.

```
{image && image.length && image.map(image => {
      return <Image 
            source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + image}}
            style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
          />  
   })
}
```

Comment: i got this error Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: @Atiffaniq, for your error you need to do this - `let image = member && JSON.parse(member.image)`

Comment: in constructor only define this `member:""` don't define as array.

Comment: You just need to change img tag with Image tag and it will work.

Comment: The code I suugested before update will work you can use it.

Comment: Have you imported Image from react native?

Comment: You need to check the docs for Image. Invalid props menas the way you are using is not valid, you missed something from docs.

Comment: i did import the image and from the doc i just follow the instruction and with your code:
<Image source={'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage' + image[0] }/>

Comment: You missed a curly braces and uri key. You should check network images part.

Comment: The way you are using is for local images.

Comment: You need to do it as you were doing before in your post. Also you dont need value prop on image

Comment: you mean the value = {member ? member.image} i should not include?

Comment: Yes. We dont need it.

Comment: Thank you it work now really appreriate with your help man thank you are genius. But i got 1 more question what is i want to get all the images in the object because if in java or c+ we use loop what about react

Comment: You can use loop should I tell you?

Comment: yess please i really appreciate because i can do for my next problem which is download the file

Comment: Where should i put this code to, is it replace my old image tag?

Comment: You can put it below your old image tag, and once it is working you can remove old tag.

Comment: i copied your code an put inside after the old image tag it give me error of "Text string must be rendered within  a <Text> component"

Comment: you know bro you are genius thank you every much i really appreciate that you have helped me . you saved my life because 2 more days i need to submit my assigment. Thank again

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197467/discussion-on-answer-by-ravibagul91-cannot-render-image-from-api).

Answer (score 0):

The below would give you some idea on the issue. ( I haven't added complete working code but a code which gives you some idea on the issue)

After seeing your api response, I see that image is an array rather than just an object. 
Moreover it's a string which you need to convert to a JSON object.

```
JSON.parse method can help you with converting your string to JSON object.
```

From your API, image is an array. Notice the `[]` which means your image is an array.

This means you either want to display an array of images or just a single image.

If you want all the images to be displayed, iterate through member.image and display it.
If you want to display only single image give below a try

Declare a variable in your render method and use it for your image. (Make sure your member object is not defined before using it

```
let memberImages = JSON.parse(member.image);

   { memberImages && memberImages[0] && 
         <Image
            value={member ? member.image : ''} 
            source={{uri: 'http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/storage/' + member.image[0]}}
            style={{width: 60, height: 60}}
          />  
   }
```

Comment: your code is abit confusing i try to edit but still i can't work is. It say that cannot read property '0' is of undefiend

Comment: @ravibagul91 added the same code.. please take a look at that code.